# Tsql Two Group By Statements in Select Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck trying to add multiple group by sub queries to a query I made (my Tsql skills are nascent) and could use some help. 
I am trying to incorporate the query "Downtime" results into the query "Status" so that each V_ShiftReportMaster record displayed will also display a sum of the ShiftReportDowntime entries (DTmin).
I have been reading through other questions/answers and this just isn't connecting for me yet- I could really use some help on my example.

The (left) join columns are: 
V_ShiftReportMaster.SR_ID (one record) =  ShiftReportDowntime.DTR_SRID (many records)

--Query DOWNTIME

```
SELECT ShiftReportDowntime.DTR_SRID,    Sum(ShiftReportDowntime.DTR_DownTimeDuration) AS DTmin
FROM ShiftReportDowntime
GROUP BY ShiftReportDowntime.DTR_SRID;
```

--Query STATUS

```
SELECT  V_ShiftReportMaster.Equ_Name as Station, V_ShiftReportMaster.SR_Shift as Shift, 
case V_ShiftReportMaster.[SR_ShiftStatus]
    when 0 then 'restart'
    when 1 then 'G- On Time'
    when 2 then 'G- Late'
    when 3 then 'R- On Time'
    when 4 then 'R- Late'
    when 5 then 'Closed'
    when 6 then 'Down'
    else 'No Info'
end as "Status",
V_ShiftReportMaster.PRT_Number as [Part Number], V_ShiftReportMaster.PRT_Description as [Part Description], (isnull([SR_PC_IsParts1],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts2],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts3],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts4],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts5],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts6],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts7],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts8],0)) AS [Produced Count], ISNULL(a.SumOfSRS_Scraped,0) AS [Scrap Count], (isnull([SR_PC_IsParts1],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts2],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts3],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts4],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts5],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts6],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts7],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts8],0))-ISNULL(a.SumOfSRS_Scraped,0) AS [Good Count], isnull(cast(cast((ShiftReportPartCount.ShiftFTTQ*100)as decimal(18,2))as varchar(8))+'%',0) as FTTQ, isnull(cast(cast((ShiftReportPartCount.ShiftOEE*100)as decimal(18,2))as varchar(8))+'%',0) as OEE, convert(varchar,V_ShiftReportMaster.SR_StartTime,100) as [Shift Start], V_ShiftReportMaster.SR_ID, V_ShiftReportMaster.SR_ShiftStatus as StatusId
FROM (V_ShiftReportMaster LEFT JOIN ShiftReportPartCount ON V_ShiftReportMaster.SR_ID = ShiftReportPartCount.SR_PC_SRID) LEFT JOIN (SELECT ShiftReportScrap.SRS_SR_ID, Sum(ShiftReportScrap.SRS_Scraped) AS SumOfSRS_Scraped, Traceabillity.OT_Number
FROM Traceabillity RIGHT JOIN ShiftReportScrap ON Traceabillity.OT_ID = ShiftReportScrap.SRS_PartID
GROUP BY ShiftReportScrap.SRS_SR_ID, Traceabillity.OT_Number) A ON (A.SRS_SR_ID =V_ShiftReportMaster.SR_ID and a.OT_Number = V_ShiftReportMaster.PRT_Number)
WHERE (((V_ShiftReportMaster.SR_ShiftStatus)<>5))
ORDER BY V_ShiftReportMaster.Equ_Name, V_ShiftReportMaster.SR_Shift;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discarded all of the previous owner's work and started from scratch on the tsql. To recap, I am trying to join a single status record with the sum of multiple scrap records as well as the sum of multiple downtime records. Below are the iterations:

```
-- DOWNTIME SUMMARY, sum downtime by shift 
SELECT ShiftReportDowntime.DTR_SRID, Sum(ShiftReportDowntime.DTR_DownTimeDuration) AS SumOfDTR_DownTimeDuration
FROM ShiftReportDowntime
GROUP BY ShiftReportDowntime.DTR_SRID;

-- PART COUNT SUMMARY, get part counts by shift (yes, this table was poorly constructed)
SELECT ShiftReportPartCount.SR_PC_SRID, ShiftReportPartCount.ShiftFTTQ, ShiftReportPartCount.ShiftOEE, isnull([SR_PC_IsParts1],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts2],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts3],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts4],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts5],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts6],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts7],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts8],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts9],0) as Produced
FROM ShiftReportPartCount;

-- SCRAP COUNT SUMMARY, sum scrap count by shift
SELECT Sum(ShiftReportScrap.SRS_Scraped) AS SumOfSRS_Scraped
FROM Traceabillity INNER JOIN ShiftReportScrap ON Traceabillity.OT_ID = ShiftReportScrap.SRS_PartID
GROUP BY Traceabillity.OT_PRT_ID, ShiftReportScrap.SRS_SR_ID;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- START OVER, JUST THE STATUS
SELECT  V.Equ_Name as Station, V.SR_Shift as Shift, 
case V.[SR_ShiftStatus]
    when 0 then 'restart'
    when 1 then 'G- On Time'
    when 2 then 'G- Late'
    when 3 then 'R- On Time'
    when 4 then 'R- Late'
    when 5 then 'Closed'
    when 6 then 'Down'
    else 'No Info'
end as "Status",
V.PRT_Number as [Part Number], 
V.PRT_Description as [Part Description],
convert(varchar,V.SR_StartTime,100) as [Shift Start], 
V.SR_ID, 
V.SR_ShiftStatus as StatusId
FROM V_ShiftReportMaster V
WHERE (((V.SR_ShiftStatus)<>5))
ORDER BY V.Equ_Name, V.SR_Shift; 

-- NOW STATUS WITH DOWNTIME
SELECT  V.Equ_Name as Station, V.SR_Shift as Shift, 
case V.[SR_ShiftStatus]
    when 0 then 'restart'
    when 1 then 'G- On Time'
    when 2 then 'G- Late'
    when 3 then 'R- On Time'
    when 4 then 'R- Late'
    when 5 then 'Closed'
    when 6 then 'Down'
    else 'No Info'
end as "Status",
V.PRT_Number as [Part Number], 
V.PRT_Description as [Part Description],
convert(varchar,V.SR_StartTime,100) as [Shift Start],
D.DTmin, 
V.SR_ID, 
V.SR_ShiftStatus as StatusId
FROM V_ShiftReportMaster V LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DTR_SRID, isnull(Sum(DTR_DownTimeDuration),0) AS DTmin
    FROM ShiftReportDowntime
    GROUP BY DTR_SRID) D ON (D.DTR_SRID=V.SR_ID)
WHERE (((V.SR_ShiftStatus)<>5))
ORDER BY V.Equ_Name, V.SR_Shift; 

-- NOW STATUS WITH DOWNTIME, SCRAP COUNT
-- V= V_ShiftReportMaster, D= downtime, C=count
SELECT  V.Equ_Name as Station, V.SR_Shift as Shift, 
case V.[SR_ShiftStatus]
    when 0 then 'restart'
    when 1 then 'G- On Time'
    when 2 then 'G- Late'
    when 3 then 'R- On Time'
    when 4 then 'R- Late'
    when 5 then 'Closed'
    when 6 then 'Down'
    else 'No Info'
end as "Status",
V.PRT_Number as [Part Number], 
V.PRT_Description as [Part Description],
convert(varchar,V.SR_StartTime,100) as [Shift Start],
D.DTmin,
c.Produced,
c.FTTQ,
c.OEE, 
V.SR_ID, 
V.SR_ShiftStatus as StatusId
FROM V_ShiftReportMaster V LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DTR_SRID, isnull(Sum(DTR_DownTimeDuration),0) AS DTmin
    FROM ShiftReportDowntime
    GROUP BY DTR_SRID) D ON (D.DTR_SRID=V.SR_ID
    ) LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SR_PC_SRID, isnull(ShiftReportPartCount.ShiftFTTQ,0) as FTTQ, isnull(ShiftReportPartCount.ShiftOEE,0) as OEE, isnull([SR_PC_PlanParts1],0)+isnull([SR_PC_PlanParts2],0)+isnull([SR_PC_PlanParts3],0)+isnull([SR_PC_PlanParts4],0)+isnull([SR_PC_PlanParts5],0)+isnull([SR_PC_PlanParts6],0)+isnull([SR_PC_PlanParts7],0)+isnull([SR_PC_PlanParts8],0)+isnull([SR_PC_PlanParts9],0) as Produced
        FROM ShiftReportPartCount) C ON (C.SR_PC_SRID=V.SR_ID) 
WHERE (((V.SR_ShiftStatus)<>5))
ORDER BY V.Equ_Name, V.SR_Shift;

-- NOW STATUS WITH DOWNTIME, SCRAP COUNT, AND PRODUCED COUNT - WORKING
-- V= V_ShiftReportMaster, D= downtime, C=count, S= scrap count
SELECT  V.Equ_Name as Station, V.SR_Shift as Shift, 
case V.[SR_ShiftStatus]
    when 0 then 'restart'
    when 1 then 'G- On Time'
    when 2 then 'G- Late'
    when 3 then 'R- On Time'
    when 4 then 'R- Late'
    when 5 then 'Closed'
    when 6 then 'Down'
    else 'No Info'
end as "Status",
V.PRT_Number as [Part Number], 
V.PRT_Description as [Part Description],
isnull(c.[Total Produced],0) as [Total Produced],
isnull(s.Scrap,0) as Scrap,
isnull(c.[Total Produced],0)-isnull(s.Scrap,0) as [Total Good],
isnull(cast(cast((C.ShiftFTTQ*100)as decimal(18,2))as varchar(8))+'%',0) as FTTQ,           
isnull(cast(cast((C.ShiftOEE*100)as decimal(18,2))as varchar(8))+'%',0) as OEE, 
isnull(D.DTmin,0) as DTmin,
convert(varchar,V.SR_StartTime,100) as [Shift Start],
V.SR_ID, 
V.SR_ShiftStatus as StatusId
FROM V_ShiftReportMaster V LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DTR_SRID, isnull(Sum(DTR_DownTimeDuration),0) AS DTmin
    FROM ShiftReportDowntime
    GROUP BY DTR_SRID) D ON (D.DTR_SRID=V.SR_ID
    ) LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SR_PC_SRID, ShiftFTTQ, ShiftOEE, isnull([SR_PC_IsParts1],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts2],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts3],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts4],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts5],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts6],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts7],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts8],0)+isnull([SR_PC_IsParts9],0) as [Total Produced]
        FROM ShiftReportPartCount) C ON (C.SR_PC_SRID=V.SR_ID
        ) LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT Sum(ShiftReportScrap.SRS_Scraped) AS Scrap,Traceabillity.OT_PRT_ID, ShiftReportScrap.SRS_SR_ID
            FROM Traceabillity INNER JOIN ShiftReportScrap ON Traceabillity.OT_ID = ShiftReportScrap.SRS_PartID
            GROUP BY Traceabillity.OT_PRT_ID, ShiftReportScrap.SRS_SR_ID
        ) S ON (S.SRS_SR_ID=V.SR_ID AND S.OT_PRT_ID=V.SR_PartID)
WHERE (((V.SR_ShiftStatus)<>5))
ORDER BY V.Equ_Name, V.SR_Shift;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not be scared to use some white space. It makes your queries a LOT easier to read. Also, using aliases will make things a lot easier to work with. Here is how I would format that query so it much more legible (I had to format this just so I could even begin to understand it).

```
SELECT vrm.Equ_Name as Station
    , vrm.SR_Shift as Shift
    , case vrm.[SR_ShiftStatus]
        when 0 then 'restart'
        when 1 then 'G- On Time'
        when 2 then 'G- Late'
        when 3 then 'R- On Time'
        when 4 then 'R- Late'
        when 5 then 'Closed'
        when 6 then 'Down'
        else 'No Info'
    end as Status
    , vrm.PRT_Number as [Part Number]
    , vrm.PRT_Description as [Part Description]
    , isnull([SR_PC_IsParts1], 0) 
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts2], 0) 
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts3], 0) 
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts4], 0) 
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts5], 0)
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts6], 0)
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts7], 0)
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts8], 0) AS [Produced Count]
    , ISNULL(a.SumOfSRS_Scraped, 0) AS [Scrap Count]
    , isnull([SR_PC_IsParts1], 0) 
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts2], 0)
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts3], 0)
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts4], 0)
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts5], 0)
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts6], 0)
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts7], 0)
        + isnull([SR_PC_IsParts8], 0)
        -ISNULL(a.SumOfSRS_Scraped, 0) AS [Good Count]
    , isnull(cast(cast((srpc.ShiftFTTQ * 100)as decimal(18, 2))as varchar(8)) + '%', 0) as FTTQ
    , isnull(cast(cast((srpc.ShiftOEE * 100)as decimal(18, 2))as varchar(8)) + '%', 0) as OEE
    , convert(varchar, vrm.SR_StartTime, 100) as [Shift Start]
    , vrm.SR_ID
    , vrm.SR_ShiftStatus as StatusId
FROM V_ShiftReportMaster srm
LEFT JOIN ShiftReportPartCount srpc ON vrm.SR_ID = srpc.SR_PC_SRID
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT srs.SRS_SR_ID
        , Sum(srs.SRS_Scraped) AS SumOfSRS_Scraped
        , t.OT_Number
    FROM Traceabillity t
    RIGHT JOIN ShiftReportScrap srs ON t.OT_ID = srs.SRS_PartID
    GROUP BY srs.SRS_SR_ID, t.OT_Number
) A ON A.SRS_SR_ID = vrm.SR_ID 
    and a.OT_Number = vrm.PRT_Number
WHERE vrm.SR_ShiftStatus <> 5
ORDER BY vrm.Equ_Name
    , vrm.SR_Shift;
```

I would also suggest you not use spaces in your column aliases. It just makes it hard to work with. The biggest issue I see here is you have some normalization problems. You have repeating columns which violates first normal form. Consider how painful it would be if you need to add SR_PC_IsParts9. You would have to change the table and every query that references it. If this was a separate table you could have as many of those as you want, and your queries would be easier to write.

As for the problem at hand...I have no idea what you are trying to do. Maybe this would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/